# Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException - Type universe cannot resolve assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, crash, visual-studio-2012, designer

I'm posting this to basically continue a thread that was closed:

["Error trying to open a VS 2010 project in VS 2012 : Type universe cannot resolve assembly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131161/error-trying-to-open-a-vs-2010-project-in-vs-2012-type-universe-cannot-resolve) by [user1766173](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766173/user1766173)

I've dug deeper into the issue and narrowed some things down, so hopefully the discussion can be resumed.

I'm using VS 2012 (and I don't have 2010 to compare to). My solution, `"TWConsole"`, was working fine on Friday, and as of Tuesday it was not. Both versions compile and run fine, but in the designer, no XAML file in the project can be opened without crashing. However, opening an XAML from a different project within the same solution works fine. Everything I've googled regarding this issue results in someone dealing with a 3rd party assembly.

However, in my case the assembly that can't be resolved is my own--the one generated by the build.

Interestingly, I've found that by "secretly" replacing the TWConsole.exe in the bin\Debug folder with from last monday's build, everything works! ... that is, until I rebuild the solution, and that exe gets replaced, and then the XAML designer begins crashing.

So there's something relating to new code I've added that is somehow "infecting" the main assembly. In the meantime before anyone can come to my rescue with a solution, I will start with the last-working solution and just add one line of code at a time until the problem surfaces, so as to pin-point the exact cause.

Thanks

EDIT: 
I've been able to narrow down the source of the problem to one line of code:

```
public static bool GetFavWashPkgs(out List<WashPkg> wPkgs)
```

If I remove the "out" keyword, then compile, the designer crashing problem is resolved. Same applies to the "ref" keyword--also a no-no in this case. I have tried for an hour to re-create this anomaly in a more basic test, using a test class and test function, but to no avail. All I can report is that this "sensitive" function is overloaded, the custom class WashPkg has the attribute [serializable()], and the class in which this function resides is static. If I modify the function declaration so that the type of List is int instead of WashPkg, the problem is also resolved. 
So at this point it's still a mystery as to why the designer doesn't like that function declaration.

Comment: Which framework is the class library targeting?

Comment: Its somewhat hard to fix your problem as it is layed out here. It takes much time. It would be better if you have some sample code that I can review showing the actual problem.